# Android:conditionally loading option into screen based on another field

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am working on writing my first usable android app. I have the following query , is there a way to populate values of a flied , based on value selected in a spinner.

e.g When country A is selected , 3 values are shown .

[image]

But when country B is selected, only 2 values are shown.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this on Android screen? can someone provide some examples or point me in the right direction.

Comment: for your options can you use listview or not.. otherwise you need to create options dynamically..

Comment: Can't user listview(Spinner). How do I create options dynamically ? Can you provide any examples?

Answer (score 0):

I think this example can help you not sure. I am creating a linear layout on which I will add all option. I am managing options in a hashmap. You can change according to your requirement.

Here is my main Activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        HashMap <String, CheckBox> options = new HashMap<String, CheckBox>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            int number_of_options = 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_options; i ++) {
                create_view("option "  + i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }



    private void create_view(String option)
            {
                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                TextView text_option = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                text_option.setText(option);
                CheckBox check_box = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                layout.addView(text_option);
                layout.addView(check_box);
                LinearLayout inner_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
                inner_layout.addView(layout);
                options.put(option, check_box);
            }
    }
```

create_view will create options for you.

Here is my XML layout:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>
```

I am simply creating a linear layout and adding options on it. If you are having any doubt then you may ask I will try to help.
I am not managing margin between options.